# opengl automatically move object for x times

Tags: c++, glut

My main loop is working fine, but the problem I'm encountering is when I click the "esc" button on my keyboard, the shape that I have should move to the right every 1 second for five times then terminate. I did a loop on it, but it doesn't work. I call this function with

```
case 27:
    glutTimerFunc(25, move, 1);
```

Here's the portion of that code I did:

```
void move(int value)
{
    int i = value;
    while (i <= 5)
    {
        pX += 0.5; //pX is the position of the object in x-axis
        i++;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
    exit(0);
}
```

Can you help me point out my mistakes? I'm still confused on how glutTimerFunc works so any tips/explanation would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use a `while` loop in your `move()` callback. The `glutTimerFunc()` indicates that `move()` is already called in another loop where other things are handled as well. Instead, `pX` should be incremented once in every call of `move()` only.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I don't quite get how `glutTimerFunc` works, because all of the examples I've seen are quite simple. If I get what you said right, I'll delete the loop and just retain the pX along with `glutPostRedisplay()` ?

Comment: Have a look at doc. [glutTimerFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html). It registers a function which is called in periodical intervals - out of a main loop which is run by yet another glut function - you probably have in your `main()` function which you (unfortunately) didn't expose. (Sorry, I'm not that familiar with glut but basically most of that window with OpenGL stuff works similar.) ;-)